Does a company in Germany have to report to an employee on accumulated overtime?
A company has a time tracking system that just tracks billable hours for customers. Sick leave and public holidays are not automatically tracked or calculated for time tracking purposes. If an employee asks the employer for an overtime report taking into account sick leave and public holidays so the total budget is easily visible to the employee and this cannot be automatically provided is there an issue?

What keeps the employees from doing the numbers themselves (on company time, of course, and probably less efficient than HR could do it)?


Sick leave and public holidays are not automatically tracked or calculated for time tracking purposes.

That is illegal. While the employer is under no obligation to do that themselves, they have to make sure it is done. So if they don't do it themselves, they have to make it mandatory for employees to correctly use the time tracking system during work hours or hire a third party to do it.
The EUGH ruled that a system to track working time has to be in place (EuGH, 14.05.2019 - C-55/18) and German courts have referenced that decision. German laws detailing how this is to work and who has to do it followed.
Currently (as of 2024), every employer must track their employees working times electronically and correctly to the current day. Exceptions for the transition period have all ran out.
The latest court decision on this is BAG 13.09.2022 which lays a lot of groundwork and clarifies a lot of duties for companies in Germany specifically.
The court clarified that the system of time tracking has to be "objektiv", "verlässlich" and "zugänglich". Objective, reliable and accessible.
Getting a report of your hours, including all overtime, sick time, holidays, vacation days and whatever else may have impacted them on a daily basis is the basic legal minimum they have to provide. If they cannot, that is a problem for them.
Please note that they are not forced to implant you a chip or ankle monitor. They have to give you a system where it is possbible to enter all mandatory data. They can delegate the data entry to you to do during your paid working hours. If you don't enter your data, then you cannot realistically expect a correct report. While it is their job to look after the fact that you do your job correctly (including entering your own data into the time tracking system), complaining about said system when you did not do your job of entering the data will not get you anywhere, other than drawing attention to the fact that you neglected your job.
TL;DR:
It is their legal obligation to give you a report of these numbers. It can be delegated to you to enter the correct data. So having a report accessible is their job. The report being correct might be your job depending on your contract.
